# SQL select statement raise No Data Found Exception even it is handled by NVL function

Tags: sql, exception, nvl

I am facing a problem with following code. When the select statement returns null. it raises a **No data was found** exception. But as per my knowldage it should be returned 0 if it returns null. Here the **sample_id** and **c_task_value** both has the same length same Variable type (**number(8)**). **n** is object of an Cursor

```
select NVL(sample_id,0) into c_task_value 
from SAMPLE_TABLE
where abc= n.abc
and cde= n.cde
and efg= n.efg;
```

Comment: Please show us the **complete** code. Assuming this is for Oracle a single SQL statement can't throw a "no data found" exception. This can only happen if this is part of a PL/SQL procedure

Comment: Also, possibly a symptom of what @a_horse_with_no_name says, your code references `n.abc.`, `n.cde`, `n.efg` but has no object `n` in scope.

Comment: Either way, this `WHERE` clause could easily eliminate all rows.  The `NVL()` only works at a row level, and if there are no rows, it has nothing to operate on.  Do you ***know*** that your `WHERE` clause can only identify one row at most?  If so, try using `NVL(MAX(sample_id), 0)` to guarantee one row *(with a possible `NULL`)* can be returned for use by `NVL()`.

Comment: yes @MatBailie it is returning more than one row. that was the reason . i had forgotten a validation . sorry i cant put code for security reason. Thank you for the help